# Android MediaPlayer Error 1,-2147483648 only for Emulator 2.2 and 2.3

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer, android-video-player

I'm actually facing a problem about playing the videos from url (streaming). These videos are playing on newest versions of emulators. I tested on 3.2, 4.2, 4.2 they are playing but they don't play on 2.2 and 2.3. I'm using VideoView and MediaController to play the videos and the format of videos are mp4. Here is the exception-log. Anyone having idea about it.

```
05-08 15:07:28.530: D/VideoView(2402): Error: 1,-2147483648
05-08 15:07:33.199: E/ResourceType(2402): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x010102ce
05-08 15:07:33.199: E/ResourceType(2402): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x010102d7
05-08 15:07:33.220: E/ResourceType(2402): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x010102f3
05-08 15:07:33.220: E/ResourceType(2402): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x01010300
05-08 15:07:33.220: E/ResourceType(2402): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x0101039c
05-08 15:07:33.940: D/MediaPlayer(2402): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
05-08 15:07:33.970: E/MediaPlayer(2402): error (1, -2147483648)
05-08 15:07:34.190: E/MediaPlayer(2402): Error (1,-2147483648)
05-08 15:07:34.190: D/VideoView(2402): Error: 1,-2147483648
```

Is there no one having solution of this problem???